# Opencart - jQuery cart total update - amend output

Tags: javascript, jquery, opencart

Running the latest version of OpenCart, in product.tpl, there is the following line of code in the javascript at the bottom:

```
$('#cart-total').html(json['total']);
```

This line updated the cart total without having to reload the page, so `$('#cart-total').html(json['total']);` outputs `<span id="cart-total">6 item(s) - $693.50</span>`

However, I have customized cart.tpl module and the cart.php language file to display the cart output slightly differently so that it outputs like this:

```
<span id="cart-total">
     <div class="mini-cart-items">6 Items</div>
     <div class="mini-cart-total">Your total is $693.50</div>
</span>
```

So, for some reason, when `$('#cart-total').html(json['total']);` updates the cart total, it removes the two divs I have inside it and just displays the information without the formatting I've set.

Is it possible to update the javascript so that it does not strip the info?

I can supply more of the code if needed for context.

EDTI:  This is the entire javascript section that `$('#cart-total').html(json['total']);` is within:

```
if (json['success']) {
                $('#notification').html('<div class="success" style="display: none;">' + json['success'] + '<img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/close.png" alt="" class="close" /></div>');

                $('.success').fadeIn('slow');

                $('#cart-total').html(json['total']);

                $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow'); 
            }
```

current code, with edits described below:

```
        if (json['success']) {
            $('#notification').html('<div class="success" style="display: none;">' + json['success'] + '<img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/close.png" alt="" class="close" /></div>');

            $('.success').fadeIn('slow');

            console.log(json['total']);
            var output = $(json['total']).text().split('-');
            $('.mini-cart-items').html(output[0]);
            $('.mini-cart-total').html('Your total is ' + output[1]);

            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow'); 
        }
```

Comment: what is within your `json['total']`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you `json['total']` contain only numeric amount then you can try this:

```
$('#cart-total .mini-cart-total').empty().html('Your total is $' + json['total']);
```

According to your edit:

```
var output = $(json['total']).text().split('-');

$('.mini-cart-items').html(output[0]);
$('.mini-cart-total').html('Your total is ' + output[1]);
```

***[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QStkd/17/)***

Comment: json['total'] seems to return BOTH the number of items, and the total amount for the bill.  It silly because you would think it should be split into two outputs, but its not.

Comment: Not sure if I understand you. I'll answer with what i thought you meant, but sorry if I misunderstood. `$('#cart-total').html(json['total']);` outputs `<span id="cart-total">6 item(s) - $693.50</span>`

Comment: While this works on your demo, it does not work within Opencart.  I am posting the entire javascript section that the '$('#cart-total').html(json['total']);' is included within, perhaps it will help see the problem.  Check my original post in a moment

Comment: It does not work on the page.  It does not update, or scroll back to the top of the page as it should (see the code I added above showing the entire section of code)

Comment: Not sure why it wasnt before, but it now does scroll back up, but it says "Your total is undefined" two times in a row.

Comment: @ZachNicodemous `console.log(json['total'])` just before above code within condition`if(json['success'])`.

Comment: @ZachNicodemous `console.log(json['total'])` says `undefined`?

Comment: Look at this - its a video demonstration: www.swaggauk.co.uk/2012-05-07_2321.swf

Answer (score 2):

I have troble with it too and I find how to resolve problem.

how to work json['total'] I find in **catalog/controller/checkout/cart.php**

```
$json['total'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_items') .......
```

but it`s not so importantly, 
'text_items' placed in two place

```
catalog/language/russian/module/cart.php
```

and

```
catalog/language/russian/checkout/cart.php
```

it's very interesting, **module file** use at first, **checkout file** use with json

here is my 'text_items' , i placed it in two language files

```
// Text
$_['text_items'] = 'In cart: <div class="header-product">%s product</div> summ %s';
```

Comment: Hey Micheal - I've found that in /language/insertlanguage/checkout/cart.php - the html code gets stripped out when its loaded - it ignores <div class="header-product"></div> and just loads %s product - did you get this issue?

Answer (score 0):

the above works, well u can always give your div an id

```
<div id="mini-cart-total" class="mini-cart-total">Your total is $574.00</div>
```

in your script:

```
$('#mini-cart-total').html(json['total']);
```

at the end of the day,  $('#id').html(str) replaces all html in the id with what you pass in.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by this

```
setTimeout(function(){
  $('#cart-total').html('Your total is $' + json['total']); 
}, 100);
```

Just add delay